# GDM3 setting incorrect refresh rate for my monitor on evert launch, despite it being set properly in xorg.conf

Tags: debian, resolution, gdm3

I wanted the ability to switch users with gdmflexiserver, so I switched from KDM to GDM, and ever since, it has been setting up incorrect refresh rate on every launch, requiring me to manually change it in `nvidia-settings`. Apparently, `xrandr --size 1440x900_75` does not work either, reporting 75 as a refresh rate not available for the given size.

Is there any way I can get it to not do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've used nvidia-settings , you must run it as root, then Save Configuration to make it a default, it will save your settings in /etc/X11/xorg.conf